# DAX ISBLANK() Showing "False" for empty cells in Power Pivot

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I'm looking to generate a calculated column based off of some other columns in a PowerPivot table.

The cells are blank - as in no discernible value - but when I reference them as BLANK(), my formula doesn't work.

ISBLANK() shows False when I reference those cells - but there is no data in the cells (that I can tell).

How can I A) get DAX to realize these really are BLANK(), or B) Figure out what in the world is in those cells to make them not be seen as blank.

The code is dead simple, just =ISBLANK([claim schdlng prvdr]) with the [claim schdlng prvdr] being empty/blank.

Not sure what the problem is. But the cell definitely has nothing in it.

Comment: Additionally - I just checked. ISBLANK() on the actual csv the data is drawn from comes up correct with "TRUE"... so something when it gets imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that those cells contain the empty string `""` which is sometimes treated differently than `BLANK()`. To test, try `= ( [claim schdlng prvdr] = "" )`

Comment: I went ahead and added a value to "empty" cells on import via PowerQuery, that sorted it out. I'm going to go back and check the "". Thanks for the assistance.